# GORM loading from YAML with associations

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-2.0, snakeyaml

So I have 3 domains, `Feed`, `Source`, and `Article`.  they are set up similar to this, although I have removed all the members that dont describe their relationships

```
class Feed {
static hasMany = [sources:Source]
    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Source {
static belongsTo = [feed:Feed]
static hasMany = [articles:Article]
    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Article {

static belongsTo=[source:Source]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

In my `Bootstrap.groovy` file I load a YAML file that looks like this (Keep in mind that the domains referenced above are snippets)

```
--- !!com.my.package.model.Feed
  name: FeedName
  sources: 
  - !!com.my.package.model.Source
    link: "http://some.website.com"
    description: "Description"
    articles: 
    - !!com.my.package.model.Article 
      title: "We know quitting is tough but stay strong! We all have bad days, and you will get through this. Do whatever to boost your mood-just do not smoke."
    - !!com.my.package.model.Article 
      title: "Keep staying strong & smokefree--you can do it! We know it is not easy but it is worth it. Check Smokefree.gov for new tools, apps, and contests."
```

Using SnakeYAML, I am able to load a `Feed` and verify that it does contain 1 `Source`, and that `Source`  has 2 `Article`s.

```
Object data = yaml.loadAll(new FileInputStream(servletContext.getRealPath('/path/to/yaml/file.yml')));
(data as Feed).save(failOnError: true)
```

My attempt to save produces this error:

```
Error |
2014-03-14 12:23:38,861 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
Message: null id in com.my.package.model.Source entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

I have tried saving with `flush:false` as well but it does not help.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post actual domain classes? I fear you have `id` generation strategy as `assigned` in `Source`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I finally ended up doing to solve my issues....

As stated in the question an `Feed` has many `Source`s which has many `Article`s. The yaml file is the same as stated in the question.  For my `Feed` I added

```
static mapping = {
    sources cascade: "all"
}
```

For source I added

```
static mapping = {
    articles cascade: "all"
}
```

The groovy code used to load the yaml file to the DB is as follows

```
for (Object data : yaml.loadAll(new FileInputStream(servletContext.getRealPath('/WEB-INF/seeds/quitsmart.yml')))) {
    for (Source source : (data as Feed).sources) {
        for (Article article : source.articles) {
                source.addToArticles(article)
            }
            (data as Feed).addToSources(source)
        }
        (data as Feed).save(failOnError: true)
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is another way to do this as this may not be the best solution.